# How can I move two viewpager2 synchronously?

Tags: java, android, android-viewpager, gesture, android-viewpager2

I have a layout design that looks like the drawing below. When I move the viewpager2 below, I want the top viewpager2 to move synchronously. the solutions i found on the internet didn't work

[image]

```
myViewPager2.registerOnPageChangeCallback(new ViewPager2.OnPageChangeCallback() {
        @Override
        public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {
// myViewPager1 (top) move to left or right sync with myViewPager2 (below)
            super.onPageScrolled(position, positionOffset, positionOffsetPixels);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageSelected(int position) {
            super.onPageSelected(position);
        }

        @Override
        public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {
            super.onPageScrollStateChanged(state);
        }
    });
```

Comment: Why not just have 1 viewpager and then split the Fragment up in to the 2 parts that you want to scroll synchronously? Why have 2 viewpagers when you could have 1.

Comment: because i need it. I will use a tablayout and when the user scrolls the viewpager the top one should also scroll

Comment: "because i need it", sounds like you have mad some bad implementation decisions that will cause you extra work.

Comment: The top viewpager is in a collspsing layout.. and when I change the page with the bottom viewpager, I want it to change in the top viewpager.. do you have any suggestions for a solution?

Answer (score 1):

It's not 100% synchronously, pixel-wise. But an easy and clean solution, which also looks very sleek (imho) could be the following:

```kotlin
pagerBottom.registerOnPageChangeCallback(object : OnPageChangeCallback() {
   override fun onPageSelected(position: Int) {
      super.onPageSelected(position)
      pagerTop.setCurrentItem(position, true)
   }

})
```

Here, a listener is added to the bottom `ViewPager2`. When a page change is detected, a smooth scroll is done on the top `ViewPager2`. Only works, if both pagers have the same amount of pages, of course.

Comment: this solution is not good at all

Comment: Why not? It's working flawlessly. If it doesn't fit your needs, you'd rather better explain your specification. On another note: You do realize that people are helping voluntarily? Nice way to show your gratitude.....